# What does "CL" mean in a commit message? What does it stand for?

Tags: angularjs, terminology

From Angular.js change log:

> ... After this CL, ng-trim no longer affects input[type=password], and will never trim the password value.

This is from one of the commit messages, so presumably it means the patch. What does it stand for? Change log?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It means *Change List*.

> Create a change list (CL)
>
> Creating a change in git is really just creating a branch.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/contributing-code

And the code review system there are using: https://code.google.com/p/rietveld/

Comment: This terminology likely comes from the [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/index.html) SCM, where *commits* are called [*changelists*](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_submit.html).

Answer (score 17):

It seems to be Google-speak. I don't work for Google so I can only guess, but I'd guess it means "changelog", in the meaning of "a small set of commits being considered as a single unit for merging", much like a Github PR (pull request). It shows up [here](https://codereview.appspot.com/85630044/) and [here](https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html) (search in the page for "CL created") with that same usage, and it shows up [all over the place](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/search?q=cl&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) in the Angular issues.

If you're more familiar with Github-speak than Google-speak, mentally substitute "PR" for "CL" and I think you'll have the right idea. :-)

Answer (score 11):

**CL:** Stands for “changelist,” which means one self-contained change that has been submitted to version control or which is undergoing code review. Other organizations often call this a “change” or a “patch.”

*from the **Terminology** of the **Google Engineering Practices Documentation** that can be found here: https://google.github.io/eng-practices/