# Build multiple binaries into current directory

Tags: go, build

When doing `go build github.com/.../foo` from any directory, the compiled binary will be placed in the directory from which I executed the command. When doing `go build /github.com/.../cmd/...` I expected all of the compiled binaries to appear in my current directory. But they don't.

How can I compile multiple/all binaries of that package into my current work dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [issue 23616](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23616) states:

> The fact that `go build` doesn't build is counter-intuitive

You will be able to get multiple binaries in your current directory when... the issue [14295 "cmd/go: go build should be able to write multiple executables"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14295#issuecomment-411862866) will be completed.

But that will be for Go 1.13 (not 1.12, so late 2019)

> This is so close to working. I'm not sure why it doesn't.
>   We should fix it for Go 1.12.
>   Clearly `-o` can't be used with multiple binary targets, but the implicit "write to the current directory" should work, and instead it does nothing.
>
> There is a bit of discussion on the proposed CL, as well s the comment that the CL as implemented breaks `go build -a std cmd`.

See [CL 143139/](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/143139/) ([CL = "Change List"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27520705/6309)).

Comment: The actual discussion thread is here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14295. At least after "some" it seems it will make its way into Go :D

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your binary using the project's file path (instead of the package name) to generate them in your current directory.

For example:

```
$ go build ~/Go/src/github.com/.../cmd
```

And the binaries will be in your current directory.

Comment: The idea is to build everything under the path `github.com/.../cmd/...` at once and not for every binary

Comment: So append "..." to your directory path (like you did). In Go, "x/..." means "every path under x/".

Comment: As I described in my question: When adding `...` then NO files are placed into my current dir. Only if I specify an exact binary to build it will be placed into my current dir.

Comment: Please post a concrete case of what you're trying to do, not an example. Post the command and the output. Use "go build -v" to enable more verbose output. I'm running the command I posted in my answer and it generates a binary file in my current directory (which is somewhere very different from where the code is). It should also work for you.

Comment: This is exactly my use case. On a CI system I have to build a Docker image. So I `cd` into the dir where the `Dockerfile` is. I need `.../cmd/cliA` and `.../cmd/cliB` to build into my current dir. I could build `cliA` and `cliB` one after another but I would like to have it in one command. But `go build .../cmd/...` does NOT build BOTH binaries into my current dir. This only happens if I specify `cliA` or `cliB` explicitly

Comment: File paths don't start with "...". Try "go build ./cmd/...", assuming you're in the directory which contains "cmd".

Answer (score 0):

From `go build -h`:

> When compiling multiple packages or a single non-main package,
>   build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object,
>   serving only as a check that the packages can be built.

But you can use this one-liner to achieve the same result (only the binaries directly under cmd will be built):
`find $GOPATH/src/github.com/.../cmd -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | xargs -n1 go build`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
go build -o main {module-name}/cmd
```